# Does order of servers in nginx config matter?

Tags: configuration, nginx, high-availability

I have a custom tool which generates a part of nginx config in the following form, for example:

```
upstream  backend  {
  ip_hash;
  server server1:8080;
  server server2:8080;
  server localhost:8080 backup;
 }
```

From time to time some servers go down, some go up and the next update could produce following:

```
upstream  backend  {
  ip_hash;
  server server1:8080;
  server server3:8080;
  server server2:8080 down;
  server localhost:8080 backup;
 }
```

As you can see, server3 has appeared and server2 is marked down. My question is following: does nginx care the order of servers presented in config? Do I need to sort output of my custom tool?

In this example the initial order was changed and I don't know if nginx will handle it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, w/ the ip_hash rotation method, order does matter.  Nginx hashes the client ip, then sends clients to one of the items in the list.  If you change the order, ip_hash will direct clients to another upstream node. Per the recommendation [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#ip_hash), I'd leave the entire list of servers in your file all the time, and simply mark it 'down' if it's offline.

Comment: Sure, that's what my tool does, but it stores the list of servers in memory and rewrites the file each time, writing up servers first, down servers next. I will change this, thank you.